# python: how to get line text where exception occur, not line number

Tags: python, exception

I am trying to use [sys.excepthook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook)

With below hook

```
def foo(type, value, traceback):
    # how to print the line that except occurs

sys.excepthook = foo
```

and use like below

```
$ python3
>>> text that cause error
```

**How to define `foo`** such that `text that cause error` being printed?

**EDIT**

Let me add the full story, to make it clear. (deserve downvotes? -) )

What I want is not print the line, is

- get the line
- if the line match some criterion, modify then exec

eg, 
if type

```
>>> import requests
>>> edit requests
```

get the line that exception occurs, i.e, `edit requests`

then exec `edit(find_file(request))`

where `edit()` use `subprocess.call()`, `find_file` use `inspect` to find the file where an object being defined.

Yes, I know ipython magics, and use it regularlly. this time I am ask to how to define it.

Comment: "When an exception is raised and uncaught, the interpreter calls sys.excepthook with three arguments, the exception class, exception instance, and a traceback object." Isn't that already what you're getting if that function does fail?

Comment: @roganjosh, Yes, it already has info where exception ocurrs, what I want is different, what I want is know how to get the line, then react accordingly. eg, like define something like ipython magic, eg, %edit in ipython.

Comment: I find something similar from https://github.com/jezdez/python-startup/blob/master/LazyPython.py, but it's python2, in python3, it tells no `text` atrribute.

Comment: I don't get it. Beyond regular exception handling, you now want code to write code? That's Skynet :P

Comment: @roganjosh, Yes. Have you used ipython, which has magic . eg, %mv %ls %edit, etc. I want to define something similar. [link for ipython magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html)

Comment: Sure, I use `%timeit` in a lot of my answers. That doesn't mean that I can make sense of how you intend to respond to exceptions here. It _looks_ to me like you want code generation; well, either have the function properly handle these cases or let it crash. You shouldn't have code changing code in response, even if it were possible

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modul [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.FrameSummary) and the passed `traceback` object's `tb_lineno` attribute:

```
import sys
import traceback as tb

def foo(type, value, traceback):
    # how to print the line that except occurs
    print("The line where the exception occurs: {}".format(tb.linecache.getline(tb.extract_tb(sys.last_traceback)[0].filename, traceback.tb_lineno)))

sys.excepthook = foo

int("text")
```

**Out:**

```
The line where the exception occurs: int("text")
```

as the the line `int("text")` line raised an exeption.

Comment: Thx for answering, but this does not solve the problem. I wanna get a string. not its line number, also I mainly want to use in interactive prompt, not in script, not sure lineno works there or not.

Comment: @Thx for feedback. I just tried, but it print empty. Here is what i do, put above code in `sitecustomize.py` (as said by [site module doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html), `python3`, then type `int("text")`, it prints empty lines.

Comment: Also tried to put above code in a $PYTHONSTARTUP file, and type `int("text")`,  it then prints `import sys`.

Comment: @qeatzy What you want an interactive python prompt, where if user type some code and it raises exception then the line will be returned? How much code line allowed to enter?

Comment: At interactive python prompt, if exception occurs, check the text of source code, if match a whitelist, exec modified source code, otherwise re-raise. That's what I want.

Comment: @qeatzy Ok, see answer now, try with `sitecustomize.py` first. It should work now.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. But it still not work. I 1 put above code in `sitecustomize.py`, 2 type `int("text")` in interactive python interpreter. *The output is *, `The line where the exception occurs:`.  seems `tb.linecache.getline` return empty string. I print the filename, it says `<stdin>`, but is there a file with name `<stdin>`? maybe that's why it return empty string?

Comment: Thx for you help, I vote you answer. Maybe I should give up on this.

Comment: @qeatzy no I am just on your problem. we are closer. take it easy :)

Comment: I am just doing an interactive env for simulate your env. Btw stdin is ok.

Comment: Many thx for you help and kindness. I will look at it too. I hope I could vote twice.

Comment: @qeatzy yw. let we clear something. You are talking about interactive prompt. But the real interaktiv python prompt what you are using now has alwasy only one single row. I guess you want to make something like an online editor. Or? Because the code what I will work if you have an external code. So you can get the line and this way and can modify it either. If it is true the testing approach with real IA python prompt give a false result.

Comment: Yes. I mostly want to use it in one line editor fashion, like in bash.  Though it would be better if it also works in scripts, but that's not needed.

Comment: I search in sys module's doc, only found sys.excepthook. Also tried to find prompt related hook, but only found sys.displayhook, which is a post-hook, not fill my need. Another approach might be use something like readline. but 1 too hard for me, 2 not work on windows without external dependencies.

Comment: [this file, lazypython](github.com/jezdez/python-startup/blob/master/LazyPython.py)  inspired me, but it only works on SyntaxError, since SyntaxError has a `.text` attribute.

Comment: @qeatzy with external scripts is working now for sure as I tested. But in one line editor you have only one line is entered. Do you want to get back that single line?

Comment: Well. Currently the problem is: In interactive python the file where the exception occurs is <stdin>. <stdin> always been replaced with the next stream which is an empty string as at the time when the sys.excepthook get the control the prompt is an idle empty prompt of course. Python traceback can return the affected line by the filename, which is stdin and points at this time to an empty string. That is why we couldn't get the line. Though I am trying still, please study meantime the [code modul](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html), which provide an interactiv console etc.

Comment: Btw the Lazy code you saw is quite old and it seems to me, that in that time this behaviour was different, since they works with the line is passed via `value` argument. Now this value only contains the error stack without the line where it occured.

Comment: OK, I will study the `code module`. As for the lazy code, it only works on SyntaxError (`type(value) is SyntaxError`, I tried and found type SyntaxError indeed has a `text` attribute (python3 too), that could be one of the reasons why it only check SyntaxError, otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the [`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html?highlight=traceback#module-traceback) module to help us.

```
def foo(type, value, trace):
    print(trace.msg)
```

The traceback object will have lots of information about where the error occurred.